# How to use Kirchoff's voltage laws in an AC circuit?

Tags: voltage, current, kirchhoffs-laws

I apologize for not having any examples, but I'm asking this just in case I get a question like this in my exams.

In a standard DC circuit, Kirchoff's law states that:
$$\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {V_i} =V_e$$
where \$V_i\$ is the potential drop across the ith element, and \$V_e\$ is the potential drop across a reference element (usually a cell).

However, in an LCR circuit, with an AC supply, though the current is in phase for all elements, voltage is not, for instance, a capacitor's voltage lags by \${\pi}\over{2}\$ radians in the phasor diagram or a fourth of the time period.

Therefore to apply KVL, do we consider the peak voltage and perform our calculations as if the circuit were a DC circuit?

Moreover, if we were to do so, how is this accurate? For this doesn't give us the state of the circuit at a certain point in time. How to avoid this?

Comment: edit:- changed root mean square voltage to peak voltage.(V$\sqrt{2}$)

Comment: I believe the law you refer to is intended to be instantaneous DC voltage with no concept of time so I'm not sure where your lag or phase concerns enter in.  A (discharged) capacitor for example has no voltage drop until it is charged.  You must calculate the voltage for capacitors and inductors using the state these components store.

Comment: For the LCR circuit, I'm assuming it's AC

Comment: Kirchhoff laws work as usual for momentary values and for complex values as well.

Comment: oh,OK Thank you. And if I want to solve for an arbitrary point in time, I take the RMS value, right?

Comment: @fhhh No, the RMS value is not useful for that. If you want to solve for an arbitrary point in time, you use the expressions for voltages and currents as a function of time in the most general case (or, to make it easier on yourself, use the Laplace-domain expressions), or you can use phasor representations if all sources have the same frequency. Just using the RMS values loses the phase information, so it won't work.

Comment: I see, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use this:

$$V_{e}<\theta = \sum_{i=1}^{n}V_{i}<\theta_{i}$$

Comment: Could you explain what these symbols mean, please.For instance, what is $\theta_i$?

Comment: The phase between the voltage and the current in each component.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot!